# Change from http HTTP/1.1 200 to HTTP/1.1 202 in prestashop 1.6

Tags: php, http, prestashop, prestashop-1.6, status

I am trying to deal whith the script, which has to return  HTTP/1.1  202 answer after getting query in xml, according to demands, but it returns 200 answer, is it possible to understand what`s the reason?

```
<?php

if ( isset( $_POST['xml'] ) ) {
$respond = stripslashes( $_POST['xml'] );
$xml = simplexml_load_string($respond ); 
$cart = new Cart($xml->order_number);
$currency = new Currency( intval( $cart->id_currency ) );
if ($currency->iso_code != 'RUB')
    exit; 
$sign_bank = Configuration::get('shopexample_av_sign');
$shop_id = Configuration::get('shopexample_shop_id');
$signature = strtoupper( md5( strtoupper( md5($sign_bank) . md5( $shop_id .    (string)$xml->order_number . (string)$xml->amount ) ) ) );
    if ( $signature == $xml->signature ) {
    $amount_paid = (int)$xml->amount / 100;
    $avangard->validateOrder( $cart->id, _PS_OS_PAYMENT_, $amount_paid,  $avangard->displayName, NULL, NULL );
    $order = new Order( $avangard->currentOrder );
    if ( $avangard->setStatus( $xml->ticket, $xml->status_desc ) )
        unlink( dirname(__FILE__).'/'.INPUT_FILENAME );
    header("HTTP/1.1 202 ACCEPTED");
  }
}
else {
Tools::redirectLink(__PS_BASE_URI__.'order.php');
}

?>
```

Comment: So... either your script doesn't return what you've set it to return, or the if-statement isn't actually run, and the script defaults to HTTP/1.1 200 - which is it?

Comment: I suppose, the problem is that if-statement is not commited after $avangard->validateOrder, but I don`t understand how it`s commitment influences the last if-statement, I just know that any output from php script before  header() function causes doesn`t allow to change header.

Comment: Of course you can output a header even if you have output data before the header - however, I can't see where you output data in that code? Anyway, if you need to output a header after outputting data, you can use `ob_start();` at the beginning of script. Read up on it here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php